# Change behavior in sonar.java.binaries property

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

Disclaimer : I have tried to post this message on the users mailing list of Sonar.

We are using SonarQube 4.5.1 and encountered an issue this morning on some project using the property `sonar.java.binaries`.

We updated the version of the java plugin yesterday to 2.8 (we were using 2.5.1 before).

The error in the analysis is :

```
[ERROR] [20:43:58.997] Invalid value for sonar.java.binaries 
[ERROR] No files nor directories matching '/PATH_TO_JENKINS_WORKSPACES/sonar/PROJECT_NAME/release/PROJECT_JAR.jar'
```

In the pom.xml, `sonar.java.binaries` property is valued with : `${basedir}/release/${project.artifactId}.jar`

Variables changes is good on analysis and jar exists in the repository.

Here is my investigation :

- When getting back to version 2.5.1, sonar analysis is OK
- When using version 2.8, if `sonar.java.binaries` points straightly to a jar file, analysis is KO
- When using version 2.8, if `sonar.java.binaries` points to a directory (in my case, `${basedir}/release/`), the analysis is OK

Is the behavior of `sonar.java.binaries`, implemented in 2.8, wanted ? or this a regression ?

Thanks,

Frédéric

Answer (score 0):

As your project is built using Maven, we recommend to analyze it using the [SonarQube Maven Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven).
In that case you don't need to define the sonar.java.* properties

BTW : it would better to upgrade directly to SonarQube 4.5.4 and Java Plugin 3.3 to get all bug fixes / enhancements in particular new rules on bug detection coming with recent Java Plugin: http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#languages=java|tags=bug|repositories=squid

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849687/error-invalid-value-of-sonar-sources) you should use double slashes for `sonar.java.binaries`