# ERROR: Invalid value of sonar.sources

Tags: java, git, jenkins, sonarqube

Trying to running sonartest but it's getting failed saying :

My jenkins console output:

```
Started by user Badal Singh
Building on master in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\DownStream-UpStream\SonaTest
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/singhbad/Bruce.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/singhbad/Bruce.git
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials BruceGit
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/singhbad/Bruce.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/Metapool^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/Metapool^{commit}" # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 0f59d8b3fd664144cc55e85f44be7cdfab224831 (refs/remotes/origin/Metapool)
Commit message: "Commit for metapool"
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f 0f59d8b3fd664144cc55e85f44be7cdfab224831
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe rev-list 0f59d8b3fd664144cc55e85f44be7cdfab224831 # timeout=10
[SonaTest] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation\SonaScan\bin\sonar-scanner.bat" -e -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 ******** "-Dsonar.projectBaseDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\DownStream-UpStream\SonaTest"
INFO: Option -e/--errors is no longer supported and will be ignored
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation\SonaScan\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778
INFO: Java 1.8.0_73 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
INFO: User cache: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.sonar\cache
INFO: Publish mode
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=524ms
INFO: Server id: AWBWzyK1kTiY3x_K-rPE
INFO: User cache: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=266ms
INFO: SonarQube server 6.7.0
INFO: Default locale: "en_IN", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Process project properties
ERROR: Invalid value of sonar.sources for App sonar.projectBaseDir= C:Program Files (x86)JenkinsworkspaceDownStream-UpStreamSonaTestNumberGenerator
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 12.706s
INFO: Final Memory: 40M/92M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: The folder 'C:Program Files (x86)JenkinsworkspaceDownStream-UpStreamSonaTestNumberGeneratorsrcmainjavacommkyong sonar.language=java' does not exist for 'App sonar.projectBaseDir= C:Program Files (x86)JenkinsworkspaceDownStream-UpStreamSonaTestNumberGenerator' (base directory = C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\DownStream-UpStream\SonaTest)
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

How to solve this error message?

Comment: Hi Badal! Please provide more context around your question like what are you trying and steps to reproduce this error. This will help other understand your question and bring in answers to solve your problem quicker. :)

Comment: Please [edit] your post and re-paste the log, formatted as `CODE`. Blockquote destroys the layout and makes the log unreadable. If you want help, don't make it hard for people to help you.

Comment: Hi Narayan,Jim Issue is solved for me now as I entered folder destination incorrectly..

Comment: Though I have some confusion over  "sonar.java.binaries=. sonar.scm.disabled=True" could you please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the error:

```
ERROR: The folder 'C:Program Files (x86)JenkinsworkspaceDownStream-UpStreamSonaTestNumberGeneratorsrcmainjavacommkyong sonar.language=java' 
does not exist for 'App sonar.projectBaseDir= C:Program Files (x86)JenkinsworkspaceDownStream-UpStreamSonaTestNumberGenerator' 
(base directory = C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\DownStream-UpStream\SonaTest)
```

You started the process with:

```
[SonaTest] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation\SonaScan\bin\sonar-scanner.bat" 
-e -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 ********
 "-Dsonar.projectBaseDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\DownStream-UpStream\SonaTest"
```

Make sure to double the `\` in order for the `sonar.projectBaseDir` to find the actual folder.

That is:

```
-Dsonar.projectBaseDir=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins...
```

See more at [Analyzing Source Code / Analysis Parameters](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) .
The [OP Badal Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620412/badal-singh) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849687/error-invalid-value-of-sonar-sources/47849754?noredirect=1#comment82666925_47849754):

> It was due to wrong folder path I have mentioned in `sonar.properties` file

Comment: Thanks, But problem was not with double \\ , It was due to wrong folder path I have mentioned in sonar.properties file

Comment: @BadalSingh OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: "sonar.java.binaries=. sonar.scm.disabled=True" do you have any idea about this property as I am newbie to sonar I am not aware of.

Comment: @BadalSingh https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SCM+support and https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin+and+Bytecode